# Minimal way to choose set $X = \{x_1,..x_n\}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ is not other sums of $n$ numbers in $X$

Tags: number-theory

Let there be a set $X = \{x_1,\cdots, x_n\}$. I want $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$ to be a unique sum in the sense that it cannot be represented by other sums of $n$ numbers in $X$ that involve at least one member of $X$ repeated.

Is there a way to find such $X$ without involving a overly huge number such as setting $x_i = n^n, n^{n-1},..$?

Edit: I do love the answer, but do we still require exponential numbers like $2^{n-1}$? Can there be a better way?

Comment: You didn't require $x_i$ to be integers.   Any $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ that are linearly independent over the rationals will do, e.g. $x_n = \log{p_n}$ where $p_n$ is the $n$'th prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$X=\{1,2,2^2,.., 2^{n-1} \}$$
works

To show that the sum has the desired property, observe that if you have a sum of the form
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$
where $x_i$ are repeated elements in $X$, then you can combine two equal powers of $2$ into one higher power of two. By repeating the process, every time you get two equal elements you get a new sum of powers of two having fewer terms. This process must end at some point, meaning that your final sum is a binary representation of $2^n-1$, and therefore has $n$ terms.

But if the original sum had equal terms, as you start with $n$ terms you end up with strictly fewer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only allowing positive integers for the $x_i$,  [OEIS sequence A107949](http://oeis.org/A107949) gives the least possible maximum $x_i$.  Unfortunately, not 
much more information is given there.